# Поведение сервера с автоматическими настройками IO affinity

Tags: sql, sql-server

Коллеги, есть вопрос по processor affinity и IO affinity. Как будет себя вести сервер, если включить ручную настройку для processor affinity и оставить автоматическую для IO affinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/affinity-input-output-mask-server-configuration-option) гласит следующее:

> When all bits are set to zero, or **affinity I/O mask** is not specified,
>   SQL Server disk I/O is scheduled to any of the CPUs eligible to
>   process SQL Server threads.

т.е., если *affinity I/O mask* не задана, или установлена в нулевое значение (что есть одно и то же, и, согласно *sys.configurations*, соответствует автоматической настройке), то операции ввода-вывода планируются для выполнения на каком-либо процессоре из числа разрешенных (в соответствии с *processor affinity mask* надо полагать).

Некоторые детали влияния *affinity I/O mask* объясняются [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/11/19/how-it-works-io-affinity-mask-should-i-use-it/), откуда, в частности, следует, что если *affinity I/O mask* задана, то ввод-вывод выполняется рабочими потоками отдельных скрытых планировщиков (в *sys.dm_os_schedulers* они имеют статус *HIDDEN ONLINE*). Если же *affinity I/O mask* не используется, то ввод-вывод выполняется рабочими потоками обычных (видимых) планировщиков (со статусом *VISIBLE ONLINE*).